# How to execute a command and read its output in C

Tags: c, unix, system, execv

I want to find path name with using which command like this:

```
system("which");
```

and then I use the output for a parameter for `execv()` function. How can I do that? Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't use `system` but `popen`.

Comment: but I have to use system @Jean-BaptisteYunès

Comment: You can't easily get what the command run by `system` produced on output, it is not intended for that. Why do you want to locate the it this way? Let `execvp` do the job for you...

Comment: Instead of using `which`, you can parse the env `PATH`. Using `strtok()`, get each path and check for existence of command in each of the path extracted from `PATH`. Or use `execvpe()`, `execle()` and pass the environment, which includes `PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to solve it in the wrong way. `which` uses the `PATH` variable to locate the given executable. Using `which` to get the path and then passing it to `execv()` is needless because there's another variant of `exec*` which does the same: [`execvp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html).

---

To read the output of a command, you can use [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>


char str[LINE_MAX];
FILE *fp = popen("which ls", "r");

if (fp == NULL) {
   /* error */
}

if(fgets(str, sizeof str, fp) == NULL) {
   /* error */
}

/*remove the trailing newline, if any */
char *p = strchr(str, '\n');
if (p) *p = 0;
```

If your binary is in some buffer then you can use `snprintf()` to form the first argument to `popen()`.

Comment: this is a programming assigment and I have to use which and execv()

Comment: Hmm. If you really want to do that, you can use `popen()` and `fgets()`.

Comment: @esrtr - if you insist on using `system()` and `which`, you have to create a pipe between the child process and the parent process. Set the `stdout` of the child process to the write end of the pipe. On parent process, read from the pipe to get the output of `which cmd`. Now with this output you can call `execvp()`.

Comment: I can just use system() . not popen(). How can I do that? is it possible? @l3x

Comment: @esrtr Your requirements are unusual. `system()` just can't do that. You can do what alvits suggested.